# Anyway to know all details of trees grown using RandomForestClassifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-trees

I am building a standard RandomForest classifier (named model, see the code below) using scikit-learn package. Now, I want to get all parameters of one Randomforest classifier (including its trees (estimators)), so that I can manually draw the flow chart for each tree of the RandomForest classifier. I wonder if anyone knows how it can be done?

Thank you in advance.

Manh

```
#Import Library
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier #use RandomForestRegressor for regression problem
#Assumed you have, X (predictor) and Y (target) for training data set and x_test(predictor) of test_dataset
# Create Random Forest object
model= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=5) #n_estimators=1000 oob_score = True
#====
#X, y = input_X, input_y

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)

# Train the model using the training sets and check score
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Predict Output
y_pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = model.predict(X_test)

#accuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred_train))
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_test))
```

Comment: RandomForestClassifier has an attribute `estimators_` that is a list of all the sub trees. You can use that to inspect the individual trees. You can follow [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html) from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks oW_21, I did see the decision_path attribute of Randomforest classifier. I have been playing around with decision_path and realized that this is rather quite complicated. At the same time, I notice that "estimators_" is not available in my code.    The following error is shown "AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimator_'". Thank you for the code of Decision Tree - It will help alot.

Comment: maybe you're missing an `s`... `model.estimators_[0].tree_` should give you the first tree in the forest

Comment: Many thanks! Overall, I think that the retrieval process of the tree structure is not straight forward and I will need to spend more time on the example that you posted to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

I think Terence Parr's answer is now partly outdated. You can get the same (and more) with:

```
print("Tree depths: ", [t.get_depth() for t in model.estimators_])
print("Tree number of leaves: ", [t.get_n_leaves() for t in model.estimators_])
```

Answer (score 1):

Max depth is a pretty useful metric, which I didn't find in the API so I wrote this:

```
def dectree_max_depth(tree):
    n_nodes = tree.node_count
    children_left = tree.children_left
    children_right = tree.children_right

    def walk(node_id):
        if (children_left[node_id] != children_right[node_id]):
            left_max = 1 + walk(children_left[node_id])
            right_max = 1 + walk(children_right[node_id])
            return max(left_max, right_max)
        else: # leaf
            return 1

    root_node_id = 0
    return walk(root_node_id)
```

You can use it on all trees in a forest (`rf`) like this:

```
[dectree_max_depth(t.tree_) for t in rf.estimators_]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select and visualization individual trees from a Random Forest:

```
# Extract individual tree from forest
tree_id = 5
tree = model.estimators_[tree_id]

# Draw individual tree flowchart
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

export_graphviz(tree)
```

Comment: In a jupyter notebook, you would do: `import graphviz; graphviz.Source(export_graphviz(tree))`